# Are you blind and deaf to your own senses when using the senses of a flock of familiars?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, familiars, telepathy

My problem is with the D&D 5e paradigm 'spells do only as they say they do'. If I am reading [flock of familiars](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/flock-of-familiars)<sup>1</sup> correctly, then already possessing a familiar weakens this spell, to the point where you'd have been better off not having that original familiar. The familiars summoned by Flock of Familiars appear to be much stronger than those summoned by Find Familiar because the spell Flock of Familiars does not state that one would be deaf and blind to their own senses.

Since possessing a regular familiar would cause Flock of Familiars to summon one familiar less, it effectively turns three strong familiars into two strong familiars and one weak familiar.

The spell description of the [Flock of Familiars](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/flock-of-familiars) spell states (emphasis mine):

> If you already have a familiar *conjured* by the Find Familiar spell or similar means, then one fewer familiars are *conjured* by this spell.
>
> Familiars *summoned* by this spell can telepathically communicate with you and share their visual or auditory senses while they are within 1 mile of you.

Whereas the spell description of the spell [Find Familiar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar) states (emphasis mine):

> While your familiar is within 100 feet of you, you can communicate with it telepathically. Additionally, as an action, you can see through your familiar’s eyes and hear what it hears until the start of your next turn, gaining the benefits of any special senses that the familiar has. During this time, you are *deaf and blind* with regard to your own senses.

RAW, does the Flock of Familiars spell create familiars that allow you to see both through their and your own senses at once?

---

<sup>1</sup> From the digitally published adventure, [*Lost Laboratory of Kwalish*](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/lost-laboratory-kwalish)

Comment: Why do you think you're not blind/deaf when seeing through a flock familiar? It uses the same ability from the original familiar, which is where the deaf/blind comes from in the first place.

Comment: @Erik the fact that the spell states 'Familiars summoned by this spell can telepathically communicate with you and share their visual or auditory senses' and the 'as with a regular familiar' is at bests assumed by the player. But according to the paradigm we should not assume such things because 'spells do only as they say they do' and so if the spell does not state "During this time, you are deaf and blind with regard to your own senses.", you are not deaf and blind with regard to your own senses.

Comment: I feel like this question could possibly use some cleanup, it seems a bit overly long for what you're asking.

Comment: @RevenantBacon I feel I would have been better of splitting it into two questions (one asking for the range, the other asking about the blind/deaf condition) however I am unsure as to whether that is proper etiquette on RPG.SE

Comment: That wouldn't be necessary in this case I think, as you're basically asking how exactly it interacts with a pre-existing familiar. Let me do an edit on what I think it could use as a clean up and if you agree, we'll keep it, and if you don't we can roll it back.

Comment: This question is being discussed on Meta: [I asked a bad question, how should I fix that?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11186)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You say 'spells do only as they say they do', but disregard where the spell says this:

> Each familiar uses **the same rules and options** for a familiar conjured by the **Find Familiar spell**.

If you do *not* read this as, "all the rules in Find Familiar apply except where they are explicitly overridden here", then your Flock can do very little - you can communicate with them, and cast spells through them, *but nothing else* - eg, nothing says that they can take actions in combat (or how).

If you accept that they can do all the normal Familiar stuff, just that there are more of them and they have a longer range (as explicitly specified), then you accept that they also have the same *limitations* - eg, blindness & deafness while perceiving through their senses.

Comment: It's also important to note that these extra familiars only last an hour, whereas a regular familiar lasts forever (or at least until it's slain/dismissed)

Comment: Does the caster's existing familiar have a 1 mile or 100 foot telepathy range for the duration of this spell?

Comment: @GcL The original familiar wouldn't but, on the other hand won't disappear after an hour.